# How to deselect points after simplification in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've simplified a layer in QGIS but all the points are selected afterwards (or have special lines for other reasons), making it really difficult to see the results. I've tried using the normal selection tool to deselect these but it has no effect.

So is there a way to get rid of the red "selections"?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see the answer now.

The red lines indicate it's in editing mode. To turn off, select the editing (pencil) icon on the digitizing toolbar.

[image]

To turn on the digitizing toolbar, go to View > Toolbars > Digitizing.